# How to call post API with image attached in body using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to to call post API with image attached in body. I have browsed and tried available solutions but didnt work(getting 400 as error). Solutions tried -

1. File which is browsed I have created a filereader object and called readAsDataURL(). It gave undefined error(bad request error)

   ````
   let reader = new FileReader() 
   reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
   fetch('some endpoint, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
     body: reader, //(reader.result also i tried)
   })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((json) => console.log(json))```
   ````
2. Second approach was creating a dataform, even this gave bad request as error

   ````
   <form class="form" id="myForm">
      <input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept="image/*" onchange="previewImage(event);"/>
   </form>```

   ```const inpFile = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('inpFile', event.target.files[0]);
   fetch(some endpoint, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
     body: formData,
   })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((json) => console.log(json))```
   ````

screenshot of error
[image]

Comment: Don't set header value to application/JSON since it doesn't support formData. I think removing the 'headers' key will get your job done

Comment: Hi @ShakyaPeiris, I have tried removing the header but it still gives me same error(as bad request)

Comment: I believe you have to convert the image into strings and then feed it to the end point.

Comment: @VinodhGanesh So is the fetch executed inside the submit event listener of the form or the change event listener of the input? If it's the submit event listener, first you have to prevent the default behavior of the form and then send the POST request

Comment: Hi @ShakyaPeiris, adding prevent default behavior was not necessary all I had to do was append the image to file formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]); and hit the API.

Comment: Hi @Drystan, yes conversion of image also will work, but when I appended image to file it worked. Thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is correct except your headers. try changing them to  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'.

you are not posting JSON data but FormData.

Comment: Hi @ciaran swanepoel, yes I added 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' in the header but didnt work. How ever I used formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]); it worked